# Split csv file on multiple csv files based on several columns headers

Tags: csv, split

I have a large csv file that i tried to split into several csv files based on certain columns in the header. The objective is to generate each file in relation to the columns of the country.

For example:

```
-->input file: file.csv
,,fr,fr,fr,ca,ca,ca,be,be,be
id,dateContact,name,date1,date2,name,date1,date2,name,date1,date2
100,2019-03-19,AA,2019-03-20,2019-03-22,AAA,2019-02-19,2019-02-22,AAAA,2019-02-19,2019-02-22
101,2019-08-15,BB,2019-08-16,2019-08-17,BBB,2019-07-16,2019-07-17,BBBB,2019-07-16,2019-07-17
102,2020-01-19,CC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21,CCC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21,CCCC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21
```

-Desired output files:

```
-->output_fr.csv:        
id,dateContact,name,date1,date2      
100,2019-03-19 ,AA  ,2019-03-20,2019-03-22 
101,2019-08-15 ,BB  ,2019-08-16,2019-08-17 
102,2020-01-19 ,CC  ,2020-01-21,2020-01-21 

-->output_ca.csv:       
id,dateContact,name,date1,date2     
100,2019-03-19 ,AAA ,2019-02-19,2019-02-22
101,2019-08-15 ,BBB ,2019-07-16,2019-07-17
102,2020-01-19 ,CCC ,2020-01-21,2020-01-21

-->output_be.csv:      
id,dateContact,name,date1,date2   
100,2019-03-19,AAAA,2019-02-19,2019-02-22
101,2019-08-15,BBBB,2019-07-16,2019-07-17
102,2020-01-19,CCCC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21
```

By using the following awk script described  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233089/how-to-split-a-file-into-separate-files-based-on-the-column-headers-in-original/233124) :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS=","}

          { for (i=3; i<=NF;i++){
          if (NR==1) { file[i]=$i }
          if (NR!=1) { f="output_" file[i]   ".csv";
                       g="output_" file[i+1] ".csv";
                       printf("%s%s",$i,f==g?OFS:ORS)>>f;
                      close(f);
                      }
         }
      }' file.csv
```

I am able to retrieve the country columns but not the empty ones(id and dateContact).
The output files is:

```
-->output_fr.csv:
name,date1,date2
AA,2019-03-20,2019-03-22
BB,2019-08-16,2019-08-17
CC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21

-->output_ca.csv:
name,date1,date2
AAA,2019-02-19,2019-02-22
BBB,2019-07-16,2019-07-17
CCC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21

-->output_be.csv:
name,date1,date2
AAAA,2019-02-19,2019-02-22
BBBB,2019-07-16,2019-07-17
CCCC,2020-01-21,2020-01-21
```

How to do this using awk?
Thank you.

Comment: I'd use `cut "-d " -f....` (Read `man cut`), and write a simple tool to transform your list of column names into the list of field numbers for `-f`.

Comment: Hello @ waltinator,
This should be on awk only and not shell.
In the test,  i reduced the number of columns to facilitate comprehension . `For additinal precision: In the header line (fields of country), several fields are empty.
The number of columns per country vary. There can be 3 columns or 10 columns per country. How to do this using awk?` Thanks.